# Django save 2 forms on single page, populate foreign key automatically

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have two forms: one that takes user information (name, birthdate, etc): formA. And another one that contains a textfield the user can input text into: formB.

formB's model has the actual textfield, and a "name" that links it to the user this text belongs to. This field is called text_name. text_name is a foreign key linked to the Name model (that's linked to formA).

In my view's template, I am only allowing the user to see the textbox they can input information into from formB, and they can also see all the fields in formA.
This means the text_name dropdown box is not displayed.

formA is currently being prepopulated with data from a different session.

This is my view:

```
def name(request):

    ses = request.session.get('ses',  None)

    formA = Name_Form(request.POST, instance = ses)
    formB = Text_Form(request.POST or None)
    formB.text_name = ses

    if request.method == 'POST':
            formB.text_name = ses
            if formA.is_valid() and formB.is_valid():
                    formB.note_job = ses
                    a = formA.save()
                    a.save()
                    b = formB.save()
                    b.save()
```

formB is not valid because text_name is not being populated. I tried populating using this line:

```
formB.text_name = ses
```

but that did not work.

How do I automatically populate text_name with the information inputted already without actually displaying text_name in my template and therefore forcing the user to actually choose the appropriate text_name manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do extra processing on a model instance of a modelform before saving, there are at least two simple options:

1. **Access the modelform model instance before saving** through form.instance: `formB.instance.text_name = ses; formB.save()`
2. **Save manually** with [commit=False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method): `objB = formB.save(commit=False); objB.text_name = ses; objB.save()`, in that case make sure that Text_Form has 'text_name' in it's [excluded field list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form).

Comment: would i put this within the is_valid if statement or before?